# What is the formula to compute the expected file size in kilobytes for a letter-size image scanned at 300dpi?

Tags: image, file

There should be a formula to come up with my answer but I can't seem to find a definitive one. Is it 300 dots per inch, meaning 300 pixels per inch, therefore making my file size be what (if I have a letter-size image scanned, i.e., 8" x 11")? What's the method to find this out? I suppose the file format matters too....and I want one that has the least loss of fidelity (how about *.JPG?)

PS:
I found a pretty neat calculator at http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/lrm22/pixels2bytes/calculator.htm that seems to help me figure out my number (and help me understand also that bit color depth matters too). It says there that, "DPI affects the size and quality of the printed image, but not the size of the file or how it looks on screen." Hmmm...that's a bit counter-intuitive to me. And I am still curious as to how to calculate my file size. Imagine I want 24 bit color. What's the formula?

Comment: The reason for my question is I am trying to calculate the storage cost of a bunch of scanned images that will be accumulated over a year's time!

Comment: JPEG is lossy. Most scanners use TIFF for a reason. And I'm not sure why you can't just scan a few images, see which format produces the quality you want along with the image sizes you'd prefer and just average the size of those images. As you said, color depth makes a difference, so you're not going to get an exact value in any case, so an average seems to be more suitable for what you're trying to do.